# Nature of function $y=\ln{(\pi+x)}/\ln{(e+x)}$

Tags: calculus

I need to tell the increasing/decreasing nature of: $$y=\frac{\ln{(\pi+x)}}{\ln{(e+x)}}$$
Diffrentiating:
$$y'=\frac1{\ln^2{(e+x)}}\left(\frac{\ln{(e+x)}}{\pi+x}-\frac{\ln{(\pi+x)}}{e+x}\right)$$
Since the squared $\ln$ is always positive I need to check the inside part, let it be positive for some $x$:
$$\left(\frac{\ln{(e+x)}}{\pi+x}-\frac{\ln{(\pi+x)}}{e+x}\right)>0$$
$$\frac{\ln{(e+x)}}{\pi+x}.\frac{e+x}{\ln{(\pi+x)}}>0$$
Which holds in $x\in(-\infty,-\pi)\cup(-e,1-\pi)\cup(1-e,\infty)$
And decreasing in rest of the domain. but it seems wrong.

**[Update]:** As suggested in comments $x\in(-e,1-\pi)\cup(1-e,\infty)$

Also the textbook-answer seems to be "decreasing in $(0,\infty)$"

Comment: Have you tried graphing it?

Comment: the last one is not 0,it should be 1 with x>-e.

Comment: @goblin graphing is not possible, it's a written exam type question. It occurs in chapter of monotonicity

Comment: What seems to be wrong? I guess you shall consider real values only, i.e. you must have $x> -e$. Thus parts of your given domain make no sense.

Comment: @Aditya, fair enough, but you can at least gauge the correctness of your answer in this way. Just type it into Google and see if it behaves correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: first you have to remember that the domain of your function is $(-e,\infty)$. Second, rewrite $y'$ as
\begin{eqnarray}
y'&=&\frac1{\ln^2{(e+x)}}\left(\frac{\ln{(e+x)}}{\pi+x}-\frac{\ln{(\pi+x)}}{e+x}\right)\\
&=&\frac1{(\pi+x)(e+x)\ln^2{(e+x)}}\left((e+x)\ln(e+x)-(\pi+x)\ln(\pi+x)\right).
\end{eqnarray}
Now check that, for fixed $x>0$, the function $f(x)=x\ln x$ is increasing if $x>\frac{1}{e}$ and decreasing if $0<x<\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: Perfectly what was needed